# Instruments crashes at zombie

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, instruments, nszombie

I am regularly experiencing EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the same line of code, leading me to believe there is a zombie, when I run the app on a device or on a simulator.

In an attempt to debug this exception, I turned on "Zombie Objects" for the scheme and profile the app in Instruments with the Zombies template. Once I get to the point in my app where the exception line of code is executed, the app crashes on the simulator and the Instruments run session stops as a result.

Is there something I am doing wrong in this approach with Instruments?

Any suggestions?

Instruments screenshot:
http://tinypic.com/r/2hhzk1f/8

Console output is empty, but here is the stack trace:
http://tinypic.com/r/xdcrqp/8

Comment: Is instruments crashing or just your app?  It's expected that the app will stop as soon as a zombie is encountered.

Comment: Just the app is crashing; Instruments just stops, indicating that the active 'run' has ended

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do.  You tap on the little arrow in the popover and instruments will show you the lifecycle of the object until the zombie reference.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the Zombie is never flagged. Once the app crashes, the run stops, but a zombie is not reported.

http://tinypic.com/r/2hhzk1f/8

The only arrow I have is at the beginning of the run, and when I click on it, the popover says the name of the app and 'Foreground Running'.

Comment: @matt It's hard to say.  That looks like the Zombies instrument.  He's just on the second tab which makes it indistinguishable from Allocations.

Comment: @matt If I am not using the Zombies instrument, please describe how.

The picture I posted shows the result of running the app after, selecting the 'Zombies' Instrument template. The approach I took is also what Apple describes, as mentioned in a link from BrianNickel

Comment: Since you turned on zombies in our scheme, try just running your app and see if you get a zombie message on the crash.  You could just be dereferencing a null object or something.  Please also post the line the code crashes on and a screenshot of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I've done two things:

- turned OFF "Zombie Objects" for the scheme;
- launched Instruments on Allocations, stopped it, checked Zombies and Ref count on the right pane, then started again.

After that during crash I had zombie info in Instruments.

Hope that helps someone!